# SELECT etat, count( * ) AS 'nombre' from commande GROUP BY etat;

Tags: symfony

how to transform this query to DQL :

```
SELECT etat, count( * ) AS 'nombre' from commande GROUP BY etat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
select c,count(c.id) nombre from acmeBundle:commande c group by c.etat
```

***Where*** clause is not included.
You should have commande entity. It will return all the fields from commande entity and count. You can rectify for your needs

Comment: I tried this at the controller                                   $query =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery('SELECT c.etat,count(c.id) As nombre from CommerceBundle:Commande c  group by c.etat');
       $result = $query->getArrayResult();                                  but when i want to show the arrayResult using var_dump($stat_commandes);  i get only the last Line!!

Comment: You can try with ->getResult(); instead of ->getArrayResult(). This is working for me. And please change the GROUP BY field with 'id'